# Use Django ORM Postgresql regex when the regex is in the database and the value is a string

Tags: regex, django, postgresql

I understand how to do Postgresql regular expression searches through the Django ORM when I am passing the regular expression. What is the equivalent when the regular expression is in the database table, and I am passing the string?

For example, the following Postgresql and Django ORM queries are equivalent:

```
INSERT INTO StringValues (val) VALUES ('abc');

SELECT * FROM StringValues WHERE val ~* '^[a-z]{3}$';

# is the same as

StringValues.objects.filter(val__regex=r'^[a-z]{3}$')
```

How would can you do the following query in Django?

```
INSERT INTO StringValues (val) VALUES ('^[a-z]{3}$');

SELECT * FROM StringValues WHERE 'abc' ~* val;
```

I.E. the regular expression is in the table and I want the row that matches my string.

In my specific case performance isn't an issue - there will be probably under 100 rows to compare - but comments on the performance of this also welcome thanks, if compilation of every regex is a really bad idea.

Comment: I believe you are looking for this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31689831/1971587

Comment: Exactly - apologies, I'd forgotten to mark my answer below as the accepted answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I perform a regex lookup with the regular expression being stored in a field value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688821/how-can-i-perform-a-regex-lookup-with-the-regular-expression-being-stored-in-a-f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
StringValues.objects.extra(where=["'abc' ~ val"])
```